# Full Cone NAT debian nftables

Tags: nat, upnp, nftables

I have a Debian router, and I'd like to set up Full Cone NAT.

I'm using nftables and miniupnpd.

My current config (Restricted Cone NAT):

```
table inet nat {
    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat;
        ip saddr { 10.2.0.0/16 } oif "ens18" masquerade
    }
}
```

```
enable_natpmp=yes
enable_upnp=yes
postrouting_miniupnpd
secure_mode=yes
system_uptime=yes
uuid=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
force_igd_desc_v1=no
listening_ip=vlan0128 vlan0015 vlan0081
ext_ifname=ens18
```

I have seen this [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/437726/how-to-configure-full-cone-nat-with-iptables) but I'm not sure if I should follow the answers since I'm not using iptables

Comment: What is your exact Linux distribution? Some details in an answer might depend on it.

Comment: Debian 12 (bookworm)

Comment: While searching a bit, it appears miniupnp on Debian 12 has a bug (within Debian setup) that might be fixable. Do you actually intend to use miniupnpd and clients that will do UPnP queries for it? Because your question is asked in a weird way: if UPnP manages opening ports, you shouldn't ask about how to configure nftables *yourself*. miniupnpd is supposed to do this (once the bug is worked around).

Comment: miniupnp “asks” nftables to open a port, correct?
Basically, I want that port that is opened to operate as a `Full Cone NAT`. This is, to accept any incoming connection to that port and forward it to the host that requested, regardless of its origin.

Comment: I'm still not sure if you're asking to get Full Cone NAT handled without UPnP (as is the case in the linked Q/A that doesn't use UPnP anywhere) or have UPnP install, when requested, DNAT rules. Each DNAT rule behaves in itsef as a full cone NAT, contrary to the implicit return traffic handled by the conntrack lookup table (which behaves as a restricted cone NAT). I won't attempt to answer this question because it's not clear enough for me. What I'm sure about: the miniupnpd version 2.3.1-1 as shipped on Debian 12.5 is broken for its nftables backend.

Comment: I want a Full Cone NAT both from rules created by UPnP and also from the normal `mascarade` rule in the question